# What templating engines are available for ASP.NET MVC Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, template-engine

I was reading some [posts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001223.html) on Coding Horror blog about working with the horrors of [tag soup](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001155.html). It seems like the only way to simplify html generation is to use a templating engine.

Do you know any templating engine for ASP.NET MVC framework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many view engines for asp.net mvc framework:

- The [Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c) view engine is built in to ASP.NET MVC
- Web forms view engine(default)
- Spark view engine
- Nhamle view engine
- …
  all community contributions on the asp.net mvc framework including view engines can be found on

http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib

Comment: this answer makes it seem like spark and nhaml (note without 'e') are part of the mvc contrib project which is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

StringTemplate is a decent alternative.

Here's the [ViewEngine (with Source)](http://code.google.com/p/string-template-view-engine-mvc/), and some [tutorials](http://websitelogic.net/articles/MVC/stringtemplate-viewengine-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 3):

[NDjango](http://ndjango.org) - django templates in .net