# ASP.NET MVC without ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As far as I know, ASP.NET MVC leverages a lot of the features of ASP.NET Web Forms, one of these services is how to get the Html response from the template .aspx file (the view). Can asp.net mvc leverages any other platform to generate html over template files (something like PHP for example)?

**EDIT: There is NO use case for this, just curiosity!**

Comment: thx for the edit but i meant Gus (Gurus) not Guys.

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523644/what-templating-engines-are-available-for-asp-net-mvc-framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can! The aspx model is just one of the view template mechanisms. There are others - you can even write your own. The key here is `IViewEngine`, with `WebFormViewEngine` being the aspx/ascx provider. [ASP.NET MVC In Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo/) covers some of this in chapter 6 "Customizing & Extending the ASP.NET MVC Framework".

Comment: Thanks for the details Marc. Will get my copy of ASP.NET MVC In Action ASAp (seriously considering it). Accepted!

Answer (score 2):

you can use other ViewEngines

- [Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/)
- [NHaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/downloads/list)