# Something like Smarty in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, smarty, template-engine

Recently, I was working with PHP.
In PHP we have a powerful template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Do we have something like Smarty in ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could argue that all ASP.NET webform pages are similar to templates, as they don't need to (and usually don't) have any application logic within the .aspx pages (it all goes in the codebehind). However, you might find that [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mVC/) is even more like what you are familiar with. ASP.NET MVC supports a [number of view engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523644/what-templating-engines-are-available-for-asp-net-mvc-framework), too.

Answer (score 4):

Quick google search :

Try one of these :)
http://csharp-source.net/open-source/template-engines

Comment: Thanks. I've been seen this web page before. But I'm looking for a Template Engine that is very simile to `Smarty`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Dotliquid?

It's old but still working great with webforms. You can even have User Controls loaded dynamically that use Dotliquid templates to present data from a database or a webapi, giving you the possibility to change the presentation layer by only editing html mixed with Liquid Language (not fully covered).

Check it out at http://dotliquidmarkup.org/try-online

Liquid Documentation at https://shopify.github.io/liquid/