# Templating Language like Smarty available for dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I really like using the awesome templating engine called **Smarty** in Php.

I'm wondering if there is something akin to this for **dotnet** for doing a project in **Asp.Net MVC(C#)**?  I have been looking and haven't been able to find anything yet.

Basically, I'd like to be able to on a pageload, access an object and the attributes of that object are then used to fill in the placeholders for where dynamic data would go.

Anybody have any ideas as to whether this is possible or what might support something like this?

Comment: Kind of the whole point of MVC, really.

Comment: Not sure how you managed to use Asp.net MVC without doing that. Your view corresponds to smarty(There are many different view engines to choose from) and your controller corresponds to your php code.

Comment: and your model is the object that has the attributes to fill your placeholders

Answer (score 2):

Check out Razor (MVC 3 required) or another one of the ASP.NET MVC View Engines:

[Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

[Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/)

Other View Engines:  [What templating engines are available for ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523644/what-templating-engines-are-available-for-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ASPX page itself as a template - you can use data binding expressions to bind the data from mark-up and then execute it using HttpServerUtility.Execute method to get the html output.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC, you don't do any business logic in your Views (which would be your templates if you will), you only do presentation logic. And for your BL you have your Models and for all the wiring you have your Controllers. I personally think it's a very clean design and you always (well almost always :P) know where everything is supposed to go.